# Mongoose how to return specific fields on save

Tags: mongoose

When you save() a new document using Mongoose. How do you select the fields you want to return?

```
const productV2 = new ProductV2({ _id: req.query.po_product_id });

productV2.save(function (err, product) {
  if (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: err });
  } else {
    console.log('product', product);
    console.log(3);

    res.send(product);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The clean way is to define method on your mongoose instance which you want to return specific fields.

For example if you have this `ProductV2` schema like:

```js
const ProductV2 = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  price: Number,
  count: Number
})

// You can define an instance method on your schema

ProductV2.methods.getSpecificFields = function() {

  // For example you want to retrieve only name and price fields
  return {
    name: this.name,
    price: this.price
  } 
}
```

After defining `instance method` you can use it in your code:

```js
const productV2 = new ProductV2({ _id: req.query.po_product_id });

productV2.save(function (err, product) {
  if (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: err });
  } else {
    console.log('product', product);
    console.log(3);

    res.send(product.getSpecificFields());
  }
});
```

To know more about `instance methods` and `statics methods` see [this](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/methods-statics.html)